# awk gsub returning odd results

Tags: unix, awk

Apologies for beginner question. I can't seem to figure this out and I've been searching/hacking for a while.  Here is my input:

```
0000000000 AAAAA~~~000000000284~~~~~~~~~~ 123456793 2017/05/01
0000000001 BBBBBBBB000000000275~~~~~~~~~~ 123456789 2017/05/01
0000000002 CCCCCCCC0000~~~00276~~~~~~~~~~ 123456789 2017/05/01
```

I'm simply trying to convert the tilde to caret.  Here is my awk:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ print $1, gsub(/~/,"^",$2), $3, $4 }' <${file1} >${file2}
```

The output looks like this:

```
0000000000  13  123456793   2017/05/01
0000000001  10  123456789   2017/05/01
0000000002  13  123456789   2017/05/01
```

Few questions:
1. What did I do wrong?
2. What do the 13 and 10 values mean?
3. If I change to `/~+/` the 13 and 10 change to 2 and 1 so hopefully answer to #2 will answer this as well?
4. I saw an awk example whereby it was appended with a 1, thus: `, $4 }1'` and this gives 50% of the correct result:

```
0000000000  13  123456793   2017/05/01
0000000000  AAAAA^^^000000000284^^^^^^^^^^  123456793   2017/05/01
0000000001  10  123456789   2017/05/01
0000000001  BBBBBBBB000000000275^^^^^^^^^^  123456789   2017/05/01
0000000002  13  123456789   2017/05/01
0000000002  CCCCCCCC0000^^^00276^^^^^^^^^^  123456789   2017/05/01
```

What does that `1` mean/do?
Thanks in advance
Cheers

Comment: Why not just `tr '~' '^' < file1 > file2`?

Comment: Why not just `awk '{gsub(/~/,"^")} 1' <f1 >f2`?

Comment: You can use [`gensub(/pattern/, "replacement", "g", string)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there:

> 1. What did I do wrong?

You are thinking that the gsub function returns the string. But your `gsub` function changes the `$2`, but doesn't print it.

Quoting https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html :

> The gsub() function returns the number of substitutions made.

This also answers question 2 and 3.

> 4. What does that 1 mean/do?

1 is a shortcut to print.

What you were doing was a mix of printing and substitution. You simply have to change the order: doing the substitution and then printing

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ gsub(/~/,"^",$2); print }' <f
```

or shorter:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ gsub(/~/,"^",$2)}1' <f
```

Comment: right and it's just worth adding that `awk -v OFS='\t' '{ print $1, gensub(/~/,"^","g",$2), $3, $4 }' <${file1} >${file2}` would have behaved as the OP wanted with GNU awk for `gensub()`.